# automated topic modeling topic naming

Tags: topic-model

Are there well-known automated methods for deriving a name for each topic obtained through topic modeling? for a specifically given problem at hand I will probably default to an algorithm on top an ontology, on top the topic modeling results. But I'm highly curious as to whether there's something that I am missing, in the general case.

Comment: you mean Latent Dirichlet Algorithm?

Comment: @HimaVarsha that would one good starting point to relate to

Comment: yes, those answers pretty much do the job I hope.